# Error: Debug Current Instruction Pointer - Method breakpoint

Tags: java, arrays, string

The exercise is to make a class similar to String using character arrays.
Here in this code, in eclipse the code is running, but when I debug it, I get in line 9 (the constructor with array parameter):

> Multiple markers at this line
>       - Debug Current Instruction Pointer
>       - Method breakpoint:miniString [entry] -

I don't know what the problem is, I am a beginner and I was practising and this confused me, I'd appreciate your help.

```
public class miniString {

char c [];
public miniString ()
{
    c = new char [0];
}
public miniString (char[] array)
{
    c = new char[array.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        c[i] = array[i];
    }
}
public int length()
{
    return c.length;
}
public char charAt(int x)
{
    return c[x];
}
public miniString concat(miniString a)
{
    if (a == null)
        return this;
    else
    {
        char [] cnc = new char[c.length + a.c.length];
        for (int i = 0; i<c.length; i++)
        {
            cnc[i] = c[i];
        }
        int i = 0;
        for (int j = c.length; j<cnc.length; j++)
        {

            cnc[j] = a.c[i];
            i++;
        }
        return new miniString(cnc);
    }
}
public static void display(miniString a)
{
    for (int i = 0; i<a.length(); i++)
        System.out.print(a.c[i]);
    System.out.println();
}
public boolean equals(miniString a)
{
    if (a == null)
        return false;
    if (a.length() != c.length)
        return false;
    for (int i = 0; i<a.length(); i++)
    {
        if(c[i] != a.c[i])
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
public static void main (String args [])
{
    miniString a = new miniString(new char[] {'c','s','e','n'});
    miniString b = new miniString(new char[] {'2','0','2'});
    miniString d = new miniString(new char[] {'c','s','e', 'n','e'});
    miniString c = a.concat(b);
    System.out.println(a.length());
    display(c);
    System.out.println(a.equals(d));
    System.out.println("The first character in miniString a is " + a.charAt(0));
}
```

}

Comment: You probably added a breakpoint by mistake. Check for that and remove it from that line.

Comment: @AnindyaDutta yeah, thank you, I found the breakpoint and removed it, it now shows no errors.
Thank you so much.

Comment: I added it as an answer so that people benefit. :) Please accept it or upvote it so that others can find it useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably added a breakpoint by mistake. Check for that and remove it from that line.

Answer (score 0):

`Run -> Terminate` worked for me for exiting the debug mode.